# How to force new records to have column values ONLY from a sequence in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, database-trigger

Please see answer below and Edit#1. However, the trigger still fails under PetaPoco/Npgsql.

I am missing something basic here. I need to ensure that **any** record added to the table has an orderno given **only** by the sequence. This should include even when the orderno is being supplied by the insert statement itself. That is,

```
insert into returntooffice (chart_recid, returndate, torder, **orderno**) values (14982,'2016-11-09','2017-12-4 00:21:42.553508', **0**);
```

and

```
insert into returntooffice (chart_recid, returndate, torder) values (14982,'2016-11-09','2017-12-4 00:21:42.553508');
```

should both result in the next **orderno** from the *sequence and not an orderno of 0.* That is, what is actually happening is that the supplied orderno (of 0) is being inserted--not the next sequence value (of 8000). I am using a trigger here since the actual composed insert is by an ORM that does not respect postgreSQL DEFAULT clauses on columns.

Here are the details:

```
CREATE TABLE returntooffice
(
  recid serial NOT NULL,
  orderno integer NOT NULL,
  chart_recid integer NOT NULL,
  returndate date,
  torder timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  return_as_needed boolean,
  is_deferred boolean,
  CONSTRAINT returntooffice_pk PRIMARY KEY (recid),
  CONSTRAINT returntooffice_chart_fk FOREIGN KEY (chart_recid)
      REFERENCES charts (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT returntooffice_order_unqiue UNIQUE (orderno),
  CONSTRAINT returntooffice_unqiue UNIQUE (chart_recid, torder)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE returntooffice
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER get_next_order_number_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON returntooffice
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE getnextorderno();

CREATE TRIGGER update_modified
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON returntooffice
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified();

CREATE SEQUENCE order_number_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 6558
  CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE order_number_seq
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnextorderno()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
   NEW.orderno := nextval('order_number_seq');
   Return NEW; 
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION getnextorderno()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Edit#1:
Renaming the trigger as suggested below, allows everything to work correctly under pgAdmin, but still fails on PetaPoco Insert. Any ideas why?

```
CREATE TRIGGER zzz_get_next_order_number_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON returntooffice
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE getnextorderno();
```

Comment: If you indeed created the insert trigger like that, the stored value **will** always be taken from the sequence. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Agreed. But the trigger seems to be ignored even when doing it directly with PgAdmin. I don't get it. :(  If I remember correctly, this did work in PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a different issue such as another trigger on that table which also has the behaviour of `BEFORE INSERT` and executes after this trigger. Remember that triggers order of execution for the same behaviour is chosen alphabetically by their names.

---

**I've tested your case.** *(Yes, on Postgres 9.5.4, since you claim that it doesn't work in this version.)* Everything works fine. Input value gets overwritten every time with a next value from `order_number_seq`.

We're starting with a value of `6558` of the sequence, and so:

```
postgres=# insert into returntooffice (orderno, chart_recid) values (0, 1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into returntooffice (chart_recid) values (2);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into returntooffice (orderno, chart_recid) values 
           (nextval('order_number_seq'::regclass), 3);
INSERT 0 1
```

And the output as expected is:

```
postgres=# select recid, orderno, chart_recid from returntooffice;
 recid | orderno | chart_recid
-------+---------+-------------
     1 |    6558 |           1
     2 |    6559 |           2
     3 |    6561 |           3
```

---

To reproduce the "issue" I had to modify create scripts by dropping constraints, replacing order of execution for different statements and removing unnecessary parts. Here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE returntooffice
(
  recid serial NOT NULL,
  orderno integer NOT NULL,
  chart_recid integer NOT NULL,
  returndate date,
  torder timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  return_as_needed boolean,
  is_deferred boolean
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnextorderno()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
   NEW.orderno := nextval('order_number_seq');
   Return NEW; 
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

-- Trigger: get_next_order_number_trigger on returntooffice

-- DROP TRIGGER get_next_order_number_trigger ON returntooffice;

CREATE TRIGGER get_next_order_number_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON returntooffice
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE getnextorderno();


CREATE SEQUENCE order_number_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 6558
  CACHE 1;
```

Comment: Changing the trigger name does work with PgAdmin, but this still fails under PetaPoco--but that is a different question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives to messy triggers. The first is to manipulate role privileges.

```
create table t (i serial, s text);
```

Revoke all privileges on the table from the pertinent roles:

```
revoke all on t from test;
```

Grant only select

```
grant select on t to test;
```

Grant all on all columns but the sequence one:

```
grant all (s) on t to test;
```

Grant usage only on the sequence:

```
revoke all on t_i_seq from test;
grant usage on t_i_seq to test;
```

Now that role can not insert into the sequence column:

```
insert into t (s) values ('a');
INSERT 0 1
insert into t (i,s) values (10,'a');
ERROR:  permission denied for relation t
```

The second alternative is simpler. Grant only select to the role:

```
revoke all on t from test;
grant select on t to test;
```

As the table owner create an insert function with 'security definer':

```
create function f(_s text)
returns t as $$

    insert into t (s) values (_s)
    returning *;

$$ language sql security definer;
```

The role will only be able to insert using the function.